# Adding the PHP json extension

Tags: apache2, php, moodle

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed. I have also installed LAMP using the [Ubuntu wiki help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP). I then proceeded to set up Moodle via the web page installation. I hit a road block when I got

```
Moodle requires the json PHP extension. 
Please install or enable the json extension.
```

With the link above, I have tried installing, whilst LAMP was still installed, only PHP5 (`libapache2-mod-php5`) -- and of course restarting the `apache2` service. The problem is in the the `/etc/php5/mods-available` folder, no `json.ini` file appears. When I type in terminal `sudo php5 -m`, `json` is not a module running. However if I attempt to remove PHP5, it shows before I confirm the removal that the package `php5-json` will go.

The question I have is how do I get the `json` extension if I don't have it already, or if I do have it (and it's placed somewhere else) how do I enable it?

EDIT: output of `apt-cache policy php5-json`

```
php5-json:
  Installed: 1.3.7-1
  Candidate: 1.3.7-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.7-1 0
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-json` but still missing file.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the output of `apt-cache policy php5-json`. Try reinstalling that package: `apt-get install --reinstall php5-json`

Comment: Have included the detail you requested.

Comment: Does php -m or php -i list json?

Comment: Neither php -m or php -i list json.

Comment: Try $ sudo php5enmod json , however I would expect something in mods-available.

Comment: dpkg-query -L php5-json , to show files.  Perhaps copy /usr/share/php5/json/json.ini to /etc/php5/mods-available if you can.  (Debian reference here for php5-curl.)

Comment: Used the query command and got the following: `/.
/etc
/etc/php5
/etc/php5/mods-available
/etc/php5/mods-available/json.ini
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/php5
/usr/lib/php5/20131226
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/json.so
/usr/lib/php5/json
/usr/include
/usr/include/php5
/usr/include/php5/ext
/usr/include/php5/ext/json
/usr/include/php5/ext/json/php_json.h
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/php5-json
/usr/share/doc/php5-json/copyright
/usr/share/doc/php5-json/changelog.Debian.gz`

Comment: @Progrock @muru I managed to get the extension working by adding `extension=json.so` to `php.ini`

Comment: So when you installed the extension there was no /etc/php5/mods-available/json.ini?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the file `/etc/php5/apach2/php.ini`
2. Add this line to the end of the file.

   ```
   extension=json.so
   ```
3. restart apache2

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: I had this problem with php7.0 and nobody else seemed to know this answer. I had to add it to `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`.